# QSTK can not be imported or not installed

Tags: python, machine-learning, qstk

I have a problem after QSTK installation.

running the Validation.py script, i keep getting 
**QSTK can not be imported or not installed.**

Current Directory :  /Users/Kornet-Mac-1/QSTK/Examples

Files in the current directory
Basic
DataAccess
EventProfiler
Features
FeatureSearch
KNN
Validation.py

Numpy is installed and the version used is :  1.13.3
Please make sure you're using version >= 1.6.1

Matplotlib is installed and version is :  1.3.1
Please make sure you're using version >= 1.1.0

Pandas is installed and the version used is :  0.20.3
Please make sure you're using version >= 0.7.3

Scipy is installed and the version used is :  0.13.0b1
Please make sure you're using version >= 0.9.0

Dateutil is installed and the version used is :  1.5
Please make sure you're using version == 1.5

Setuptools is installed and the version used is :  18.5
Please make sure you're using version >= 0.6

datetime is installed and can be imported

All dependencies are installed and working

Error : QSTK can not be imported or not installed.